# How to get a signed CA certificate for a localhost Web Socket Server?

Tags: ssl, rust, localhost, ssl-certificate

I have a "Database" written in rust that is used to manage all of the stored information from a website of mine.  In order to have the Javascript client communicate with this database I have written in rust, I decided to host a TCP to Web Socket Server (TLS) from within the database, so that once communicated, it would have instant and direct access to all of the information.  This is the fastest and most efficient method I could think of and it worked when tested locally.  My issue now, is that when attempting to accept connections with an "acceptor" that would perform TLS handshakes bringing the tcp connection to a wss using the crate `native_tls`, I would receive the error:

```
IO error: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 42
```

I figured that I couldn't use *Lets Encrypt*'s **Certbot** because this isn't a website I am hosting with a dedicated domain, but a web server binded to a local IP address.  Bringing up another question, how would I even remotely have someone connect this is websocket of mine if it's binded locally?  How could I bind the web socket server to a domain that I own which leads to my external IP?  How would I go about getting a valid CA signed certificate for a web socket server?

Here is the rust code that I have for the networking portion:

```rs
fn handle_client(
    stream: Result<TcpStream, IoError>,
    thread_acceptor: Arc<TlsAcceptor>,
    thread_data: Arc<Mutex<Database>>,
) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut websocket = accept(thread_acceptor.accept(stream?)?)?;
    // Irrelevant Code ...
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let identity = Identity::from_pkcs12(
        &{
            let mut identity = vec![];
            File::open("identity.pfx")?.read_to_end(&mut identity)?;
            identity
        },
        "PASSWORD",
    )?;

    //  TLS Acceptor
    let acceptor = Arc::new(TlsAcceptor::new(identity)?);

    //  The entire database
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Database::new()));

    //  Begin running the server
    for stream in TcpListener::bind("192.168.4.30:100")?.incoming() {
        let thread_data = data.clone();
        let thread_acceptor = acceptor.clone();

        spawn(move || {
            if let Err(Error::Text(error)) = handle_client(stream, thread_acceptor, thread_data) {
                println!("{}", error)
            }
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

If you'd like to view the rest of the code, [here](https://github.com/Daemitrious/datars) is the github repository.

Comment: (1) 'Self-signed CA certificate' is a contradiction in terms. (2) The answer to your second question is port forwarding, which will put your server on the domain, which is then (3) the answer to your first question: but (4) you don't want to do this. You don't want to expose your database to client-side Javascript. It is the web-app that should communicate with the database, and it can do that locally, and it therefore doesn't need SSL at all.

Comment: @user207421 What do you mean by "Web-App"?  Also, I don't see the problem with "exposing" my database to any client-side Javascript.  I only allow Json binary data to be transferred between client and server side and I parse the controlled commands through the `client_handler`.  I understand that I need to forward the port that I am using for this websocket, but I'm confused how I would bind it to the IP that I need it to be binded to.  Does it bind to my external IP automatically after forwarding the port?

Comment: I mean the website. At least put the Javascript server-side, that makes it kind of a webapp.

Comment: @user207421 I thought that it would all flow together if I hosted the wss from the same machine hosting the website and connect client-side using javascript through the website.  Why would hosting it with Javascript make it a webapp and what would be the benefit of doing this?

Comment: Server-side code makes it a webapp, and doing the connection to the database locally from the webapp means you don't need SSL or a certificate, as I've already stated.

Comment: @user207421 Ok that makes sense.  I'm now using `ProxyPassReverse` through Apache hosting my website.  From what I understand, I can now use apache as an in-between "webapp" I suppose that acts as a TLS web socket server which communiates between the client and that actual server side host.